# How to hide 'load' animation in the end of loading all AngularJS components and elements?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm working on UI on CRM. When I click on button, it is showing an `iframe` with lots of sections and with fields in it. Like in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKuzx.png).

So I added 'load' animation on click button. And I have to call Hide Animation function, when the document **(including all components)** will be loaded.
There are too many suggestions in the internet such as

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
       HideLoading();
   }, false);
```

or

```
window.document.body.onload = HideLoading;
```

No one is working correctly as they described. All these events are working before AngularJS Components will be loaded.

**In which event I must call my function  which will triggered after all components and elements will be fully loaded?**

Comment: did you try a console.log to see if you even get to that point in your code?

Comment: yes, also I went step by step with debugger to see when it is calling this events. This works when HTML main code is loaded, but there are multiple AngularJS components in my code, which is not waiting to load them all fully. There is also one way, angular.element(funtion(){ HideLoading();});  this part I wrote in components function (I have 5 components and 1 shared function which works with all components), but still it is not working correctly, after one component load it is working, but there are still 4 components to run...

Comment: In short my function works fine, but it is working earlier then before all components will be fully loaded.